# Manage multiple TCP socket nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, socket.io

I have an array like this:

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
var net = require('net');

exports.config = [
    {
        ip: "127.0.0.1", 
        id: 1,
        socket:  new net.Socket(),
        data: "",

    },
    {
        ip: "192.168.5.242",    
        id: 2,
        socket:  new net.Socket(),
        data: "",

    }
];
```

I'm trying to connect each of this items with a TCP socket with this code:

```
for(var key in tornelli.config) {
    tornelli.config[key].socket.connect(4000, tornelli.config[key].ip, function() {
        console.log('CONNECTED TO: '+tornelli.config[key].ip);

    });

    tornelli.config[key].socket.on('data', function(data) {

       ...........

    });


    tornelli.config[key].socket.on('error', function(error){
         console.log(error);
    });

}
```

But somethings get wrong because in the console output I get

```
CONNECTED TO: 192.168.5.242
```

But actually I'm connected with '127.0.0.1'. It seems that I don't separate each tcp stream. How can I have two separate tcp stream, one every item in this array?

It's somethings about asynchronous execution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, `for` loops are not "blocks". You can put `var` in there if you want but it will still be "hoisted" to the top of your function. Everything is fine in your initial function calls  - `key` will be 0, and then 1, and the loop will run twice. But when the CALLBACKS are executed, `key` will always be 1 - its last value. The callbacks are asynchronous, so they will be fired well after the `for` loop has done its thing.

Javascript has a `forEach` operator that makes tasks like this simpler. Try the following (or simply break out your socket-handling code to a function that takes the config block as a parameter):

```
tornelli.config.forEach(function(config) {
    config.socket.connect(4000, config.ip, function() {
        console.log('CONNECTED TO: '+config.ip);
    });

    config.socket.on('data', function(data) {
       ...........
    });

    config.socket.on('error', function(error){
         console.log(error);
    });
}
```

For what it's worth, it's also really unusual to pre-create things like sockets inside config files. A more standard pattern would be to do the `new net.Socket()` call inside the above code, not in the config file.